# ¿Cómo puedo llamar una tabla de una base datos?

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, javafx, intellij-idea

Lo que busco es mandar llamar una tabla llamada offices de la base de datos llamada classicmodels, solo me aparecen los encabezados en el reporte PDF que estoy haciendo y el IDE me indica que no estoy usando el metodo getAll()

```
public class ProductDAO {
    Connection conn;
    List<Offices> officesList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ProductDAO(Connection conn)
    {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    public List<Offices> getAll(){
        try {
            String query = "select * from offices";
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next())
            {
                officesList.add(
                        new Offices(
                                rs.getString("officeCode"),
                                rs.getString("city"),
                                rs.getString("phone"),
                                rs.getString("addressLine1"),
                                rs.getString("addressLine2"),
                                rs.getString("state"),
                                rs.getString("country"),
                                rs.getString("postalCode"),
                                rs.getString("territory")));
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return officesList;
    }
```

Lo mando llamar con este metodo:

```
 for(Offices office: productDAO.getAll()){
            process(table, office, font, false);
        }
```

y el IDE me dice los siguientes errores:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Tu codigo no parece tener ningun error.. si solo te muestra encabezados, es porque no estas llenando los otros datos... y si la ide te dice que no estas llamando a ese metodo, sera que no lo estas llamando?

Comment: No hay problema... productDAO es una clase comun??? si no es estatica, deberias instanciarla primero, no?

Comment: Si, es una clase común. ¿Como la instancio?

Comment: como instancias todo el resto de las clases que estas mostrando en tu codigo... Entendes todo tu codigo?

Comment: Pues es el mismo codigo de mi maestro, solo que para una tabla diferente pero de la misma base

Comment: ok.. entonces no entendiste como se instancia un objeto... o tu maestro declaro la clase como static, o hizo un new de la clase.. asi que te recomendaria, entonces, que le preguntes y refresques los conceptos....

Comment: Pues lo unico que hice fue copy and paste a su codigo y cambie el nombre de las variables

Comment: seguramente cambiaste un nombre mal, y por eso tenes el problema que estas teniendo.. ProductDAO es el nombre de una clase.. tenes que instanciar esa clase para usarla...